# How can I sync installed extensions to another matchine?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I have 2 remote servers which has almost the same system environment except that one doesn't connect to the Internet. So I want to install extensions on the connected one and copy the .vscode-server/extension dir to the unconnected one.

However, I fond that the vscode-server on the unconnected one can't recognize the copied extensions, is there any way to make my ieda work?

Answer (score 0):

After some tryings, I found the key file is `.vscode-server/data/User/extensions.json`,copy this file at the same time makes the extensions work.